# Check if a string contains a value from an array

Tags: html, jquery

What I'm trying to do is conditionally display a div based on user input. I'd like to parse through the input and if it contains somewhere within it (The input could be a whole paragraph) one of several keywords that are in an array, then it will return true and display the div. This is what I have so far:

```js
 jQuery(function($) {
   $(".conditional-content-container").hide());
    var user_input = $(":input[name=input_4]");
    user_input.change(function() {
    if (user_input.val().indexOf(["hello", "world", "foo"]) !== -1) {
      $(".conditional-content-container").show();
    } else {
      $(".conditional-content-container").hide();
    }
   });           
});
```

```html
<div class="conditional-content-container">
    Content to be displayed if user input contains the words "hello" or "world" or "foo" somewhere within it
</div>
```

Comment: Is val() a single word or multiple?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: The value of the user input will be multiple words

Comment: I've been looking into it but I'm really confused about how I should be using some() in this case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over the array and check if they exist in the string

```js
var words = ['apple', 'foo', 'bar']

function hasAnyWords(str) {
  return words.some(word => str.indexOf(word) > -1);
  // return words.some(function(word){  
  //  return str.indexOf(word) > -1;
  //});
}

function hasAllWords(str) {
  return words.every(word => str.indexOf(word) > -1);
  // return words.every(function(word){  
  //  return str.indexOf(word) > -1;
  //});
}

console.log(hasAnyWords('I like an apple'));
console.log(hasAnyWords('I like a pear'));
console.log(hasAllWords('I like an apple'));
console.log(hasAllWords('I like a bar foo apple'));
```